# Creating and naming multiple, simultaneous threads with a for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a way to create multiple threads that run simultaneously with a for loop? Consider this example:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=36; i++) {
     if(new Random().nextInt(2)==0){
         ActionThread nr = new ActionThread();
     }
}
```

I don't want the threads to be killed after completion of the if statement. The end of each thread is randomly determined in the ActionThread class itself. Also, how do I name the threads automatically? For example, instead of nr, the first thread should be named nr1, the second nr2, the third nr3, and so on.

Comment: Seems we want to know the context more on why you need to do it before giving the answer. Can you please explain bit on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is `ActionThread`? There's no such thing in the Java SDK. Please make sure you provide enough information for readers to understand the problem/question.

Comment: It's a simulation of a gas station. At some average time a new customer is coming. For every customer a new ActionThread is being created. In every ActionThread, there are several randomly created amounts of time (Pumping time, paying time,...) All these threads should run simultaneously, so at every gas pump and the register queues are formed. So after a customer has pumped gas and payed he leaves and the corresponding ActionThread gets killed. I hope this explains it a little.

Comment: Amounts of time must not be randomly created unless you are just writing some test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `ActionThread` is some custom class that you have created that extends `Thread`.

> I don't want the threads to be killed after completion of the if statement.

They won't be.  However, it doesn't look like you have started them yet.  Read the javadocs for `Thread`.  Read the material at the top, then look at the `start()` and `run()` methods.

If you don't start a thread ... nothing happens.

Also, if you want some other part of your application to be able to "do things" to the threads once they have been created, you should replace the `nr` local variable with a data structure that the the rest of the application can get at; e.g. a list or an array.

(It is also possible to find extant threads via the `ThreadGroup` tree, but it is complicated.)

> Also, how do I name the threads automatically?

Call `Thread.setName()`, or pass the thread name to the (relevant) `Thread` constructor.  For example:

```
  nr.setName("thr" + i);
```

Or you could even make your `ActionThread` set its own name in the constructor.

---

I should also point out that is is generally considered to be a bad idea to create subclasses of `Thread`.  It is better to put your thread logic into a custom `Runnable` class, then create and pass a `Runnable` instance as a `Thread` construct argument.  Like this:

```
    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
         @Override
         public void run() {
              // thread logic goes here
         }
    }

    Thread th = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
    th.start();
```

If you want to pass parameters to the thread logic, add a constructor to your runnable class with some arguments, and provide them when you instantiate the runnable.

Why do it this way?  Because it allows you to easily change your code to use a thread loop or executor or some such.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    List<ActionThread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++) {
        if (new Random().nextInt(2) == 0) { // no idea why you have put this
                                            // but seems unecessary
            ActionThread thread = new ActionThread();
            threads.add(thread);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
class ActionThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Write what to do in Thread here
    }
}
```

Once the list of `ActionThread` is there you have handle to all the Threads that you have created. using `threads.get(index)`. From question its appears that by name you meant handle to `Thread` instance

Answer (score 0):

For automatic naming, may be use static field (counter) in ActionThread and increment him in the constructor, before generate thread name.

```
 class ActionThread extend Thread {
      private static int id = 0;
      ActionThread() {
           setName(String.format("n%d", ++id);
      }
 }
```